# Using xmlstarlet to extract HTML

Tags: html, bash, xmlstarlet, mediawiki-extensions

I am trying to extract a particular section of a HTML document from a bash shell script and have been using `xmlstarlet sel`  but I can't quite get it to return actual HTML, rather than just the text values from the HTML tags.

I'm trying a command line as follows:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//div[@id='mw-content-text']" -v "." wiki.html
```

But it is giving text only, without any HTML/XML markup.  For info, I'm trying to export this data into a HTML format outside the mediawiki instance it has come from.

If xmlstarlet is the wrong tool, any suggestions for other tools also gratefully received!

Comment: Try `xmllint` with option `--html` to enable its HTML parser.

Comment: That's what I was trying before but the Centos versions of libxml don't seem to support xpath, so I started looking at alternatives

Comment: Are you sure you really want to make your own tool for HTML export from MediaWiki? The modern solution is parsoid+mwoffline https://sourceforge.net/p/kiwix/other/ci/master/tree/mwoffliner/ ; with older releases you can try the dumpHTML extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-v` means `--value-of` which is the contents of tags. You should use `-c` or `--copy-of` to get the tags themselves.

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//div[@id='mw-content-text']" -c "." wiki.html
```

Or just

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c "//div[@id='mw-content-text']" wiki.html
```